# Solaris "installf" commnd equivalent in Linux

Tags: linux

in there any equivalent command exists in Linux, for Solaris "installf" ?

Answer (score 0):

[installf](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?installf%201) is related to package management on Solaris.

Various Linux distributions have different [package managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system):

- Debian and Ubuntu use `.deb` packages, with `apt-get` or `aptitude` command, e.g. `apt-get install sbcl` to install the `sbcl` package and its dependencies.
- Redhat, Fedora and Maegia use `.rpm` packages, with e.g. `yum` command

Some other distributions have other package managers, see [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems).